# SSL On REST Endpoint in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, ssl, endpoint

I have SSL working for my SOAP endpoint.

But as soon as I enable my REST endpoint, it throws a fit:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
```

My **app.config:**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IIncreasedBufferSize" maxBufferSize="1024000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1024000" />

          <security mode ="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType= "None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFBehaviourSSL"
        name="IWCF.IService">
        <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IIncreasedBufferSize"
          contract="IWCF.IServices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="rest"
                  address="rest"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="IWCF.IServices"
                  behaviorConfiguration="REST" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary2/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFBehaviourSSL">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

I found this question: [REST WCF Service Over SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651431/rest-wcf-service-over-ssl)
But rest assured, None of the answers provided are of use.

I have certificates, and it does work with SSL using the SOAP end point. (when rest endpoint is commented out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing a WebHTTPBinding, that uses Transport security:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="REST SSL">
      <security mode ="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType= "None" />
      </security>
    </binding>                
  </webHttpBinding>
```

. . .

```
    <endpoint name="rest"
              address="rest"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="IWCF.IServices"
              behaviorConfiguration="REST" 
              bindingConfiguration="REST SSL"/>
```